# How replaceAll "/" in java String to format URL?

Tags: java, regex

```
String url = "d://test////hello\\\hello";
String separator = File.separator;
url = url.replaceAll("\\*", separator);
url = url.replaceAll("/+", separator);
```

I want to format those `url`, but error occurs when i attempt to use `replaceAll("/+", separator)`. and i attempt to escaped `"/"` as `"\\/"`, it still doesn't work..

This is the Exception from console:

```
Exception in thread "main" **java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException**: String index out of range: 1
    at java.lang.String.charAt(String.java:686)
    at java.util.regex.Matcher.appendReplacement(Matcher.java:703)
    at java.util.regex.Matcher.replaceAll(Matcher.java:813)
    at java.lang.String.replaceAll(String.java:2189)
```

---

**Now it works**

```
 String separator = null;
 if(File.separator.equals("/")) {
    separator = "/";
    url = url.replaceAll("/+", separator);
    url = url.replaceAll("\\\\+", separator);
 } else {
    separator = Matcher.quoteReplacement(File.separator);
    url = url.replaceAll("/+", separator);
    url = url.replaceAll("\\+", separator);
 }
```

---

:) it works in javascript

```
var i = "d:\\ad////df";
alert(i.replace(/\/+/g, '\\'));
```

Comment: What error?  That seems to work for me

Comment: it is out of bound exception, try to check the `java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 1 at java.lang.String.charAt(String.java:686) at `

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your platform is Windows right?  So `File.separator` will be a backslash right?

The explanation is that the 2nd argument of `String.replaceAll` is not a simple String.  Rather it is a replacement pattern ...

The [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) says:

> *"Note that backslashes (\) and dollar signs ($) in the replacement string may cause the results to be different than if it were being treated as a literal replacement string; see Matcher.replaceAll. Use Matcher.quoteReplacement(java.lang.String) to suppress the special meaning of these characters, if desired. "*

So your replacement String that consists of a single backslash is an invalid literal replacement string.  You need to quote the separator String ... like the javadoc says.

<sub>(It is a little surprising that you get that particular exception.  I can imagine how it could happen, but I'd have thought that they'd deal with bad escapes more elegantly.  Mind you, if this was reported as a "bug", Oracle would probably not fix it.  A fix would break backwards compatibility.)</sub>

Comment: Follow your tips, now it works properly, Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
url = url.replaceAll("\\\\+", separator);
```

You need 4 backward slashes. Escape once for Java string and once for regex meta-character. That is for regex you need two backward slashes `\\`, and in string you need to escape both of them with another two.

Also, the quantifier `*` means zero or more, you need to use `+`.

Comment: Thanks you, - - but it throws the same exception.

Comment: It works for me, but I am using Ubuntu. Check out @Stephen's answer also. The end result in my case is `d:/test/hello/hello`.